# ImageKit.io list just the url of all pictures existing in a folder

Tags: python, imagekit

I'm trying to list just the URLs of all the pictures I have in the "zoz" folder in my imagekit.io account.
I have tried doing it with `list_files['url']` but I got a KeyError

```
from imagekitio import ImageKit
import os
PRIVATE_KEY = os.environ.get('PRIVATE_KEY')
PUBLIC_KEY = os.environ.get('PUBLIC_KEY')

imagekit = ImageKit(
    private_key=PRIVATE_KEY,
    public_key='PUBLIC_KEY',
    url_endpoint='https://ik.imagekit.io/ShaiTestingPython'
)

list_files = imagekit.list_files({"path": "zoz"})
```

The type of `list_files` is dict but I still cant get the key value for some reason